# How to return a JSON with Flask back-end, that works in Safari?

Tags: html, json, flask, web-applications

I have spend several days on this issue and searched for a long time. I even went through an entire debug session using GPT-4.

I have a simple login-page build in Flask with firebase authentication. I catch a few errors when the username-password is not correct, etc...

**Problem:** It all works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but it fails in Safari. The error I get in Safari Console is : `The string did not match the expected pattern.` And it specifically refers to the event-handler in my html code (see below), in particular the line: `return response.json();`

This is my Flask code for the home (login) route:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if 'user' in session:
        return redirect('/chat')

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        action = request.form.get('action')

        if action == "login":
            try:
                user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

                # Check if email is verified
                user_info = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
                if not user_info['users'][0]['emailVerified']:
                    return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Please register your email address.'}), 400

                # if it is, start a session and redirect
                session['user'] = email
                return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Login successful.', 'redirect': '/chat'}), 200
                # return redirect('/chat')
            except:
                return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Password or email is not correct.'}), 400
        elif action == "register":
            try:
                user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
                auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
                create_new_user_in_firestore(email)
                return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Please check your email to verify your account.'}), 201
            except:
                return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Failed to register.'}), 400
       

    return render_template('home.html')
```

The following is the part of the home.html file that handles the click-events:

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById("authForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                
                var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
                var password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
                // var action = event.submitter.value;
                // var action = event.target.querySelector('button[type="submit"]:focus').value;
                var action = document.activeElement.value;

                fetch("/", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                        action: action
                    })
                })
                // .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    // console.log("Server response:", response.text());
                    return response.json();
                    })
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.status === "success") {
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            window.location.href = data.redirect;
                        } else {
                            alert(data.message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                });
            });

    </script>
```

**What I have tried:** I have already made sure that the right json responses are returned if there is no event-handler in the html file. Meaning, if I fill in the right log-in, it will return the right json, if an email-pwd is wrong it also returns the right json. It's from the moment I implement the event listener it fail *in Safari*.

**What I expect:** Error messages that pop up on the client's screen whenever a email-pwd is not correct or not registered. If it is correct, redirect to /chat route.